# How do I get back to a linux mint 17.3 Rosa desktop after a system crush

Tags: linux-mint

I happen to be using Linux Mint 17.3 Rafaela. When I was trying to install Google Chromium from the terminal, later on I just remember seeing uninstalling libraries...Then everything started looking strange. When I decided to reboot, I couldn't get back to the desktop. I landed somewhere in a terminal *tty1* of which I logged in, in the terminal, I would still see that data on the desktop still existed using the root directory. Later on I discovered there were *6* different terminals *tty1* - *tty6*. I tried all I could but all in vain. What do I do because my data is not backed up anywhere

Comment: be consistent if you have a crush on Rosa just let her know how you feel.

Answer (score 0):

While still in tty1 type:

```
startx
```

if that doesn't work:

```
sudo startx
```